# How to append attribute for object in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object

Example:

```
user : {
    "user_name" : "chicken_01",
    "password" : "123456",
    "skills" : {
        "PHP" : 7.0,
        "NodeJs" : 8.0,
        "MongoDB" : 8.0
    }   
}
```

I want to add `"HTML/CSS" : 8.0` to `"skills"` inner object. What is the proper way to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you read at least one introduction into JS objects?

Answer (score 1):

is it like JS? if yes :

```
var userObj= JSON.parse(user);
userObj.skills.HTMLCSS = 8.0;
user = JSON.stringify(userObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.users.update(
                 {'user_name' : 'chicken_01'}, 
                 {'$set' : 
                        {
                         "skills.HTML/CSS":8.0
                        }
                 })
```

Except with the name of your collection and not `db.users`.